I use facebook_app_events package and now getting error in xcode
I use the facebook_app_event package in the Futter app when trying to build an ios app using code getting errors like the screenshot below.
I try to change the  FBAudienceNetwork version in the profile but not working.

I also try this one :

FBAEMKit (17.0.2):

FBSDKCoreKit_Basics (= 17.0.2)


FBAudienceNetwork (6.15.1)
FBSDKCoreKit (17.0.2):

FBAEMKit (= 17.0.2)
FBSDKCoreKit_Basics (= 17.0.2)


FBSDKCoreKit_Basics (17.0.2)

